# Run multiple scrapy spiders at once using scrapyd

Tags: python, screen-scraping, scrapy, scrapyd

I'm using [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) for a project where I want to scrape a number of sites - possibly hundreds - and I have to write a specific spider for each site. I can schedule *one* spider in a project deployed to scrapyd using:

```
curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=myproject -d spider=spider2
```

But how do I schedule *all* spiders in a project at once?

All help much appreciated!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

My solution for running 200+ spiders at once has been to create a custom command for the project.  See http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/commands.html#custom-project-commands for more information about implementing custom commands.

**YOURPROJECTNAME/commands/allcrawl.py** :

```
from scrapy.command import ScrapyCommand
import urllib
import urllib2
from scrapy import log

class AllCrawlCommand(ScrapyCommand):

    requires_project = True
    default_settings = {'LOG_ENABLED': False}

    def short_desc(self):
        return "Schedule a run for all available spiders"

    def run(self, args, opts):
        url = 'http://localhost:6800/schedule.json'
        for s in self.crawler.spiders.list():
            values = {'project' : 'YOUR_PROJECT_NAME', 'spider' : s}
            data = urllib.urlencode(values)
            req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
            response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
            log.msg(response)
```

Make sure to include the following in your settings.py

```
COMMANDS_MODULE = 'YOURPROJECTNAME.commands'
```

Then from the command line (in your project directory) you can simply type

```
scrapy allcrawl
```

Comment: Great, I Will try this first thing in the morning. I have no computer at the moment. Thank's for helping out!

Comment: Hi. I tried your solution but I receive the follwoing import error:

import error: No module named commands

I put the line "COMMANDS_MODULE = 'YOURPROJECTNAME.commands'" in the settings file in the project directory. Is this correct?

Comment: @user1009453 Make sure your commands folder has an `__init__.py`

Comment: Thank's for staying with me on this, i really helps. Ok, I've included an __ini__.py file in the commands directory and uploaded th project again to scrapyd. But now I get the following error:
NotImplementedError

Do I have to implement/instantiate the command?

Comment: What is the structure inside schedule.json ?

Comment: Can anyone explain me, how multiple spiders crawl by this custom command?

Comment: How do I pass argument? Eg: -a query="myquery" with this?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I know this is an old topic, but I've started learning scrapy recently and stumbled here, and I don't have enough rep yet to post a comment, so posting an answer.

From [the common scrapy practices](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#distributed-crawls) you'll see that if you need to run multiple spiders at once, you'll have to start multiple scrapyd service instances and then distribute your Spider runs among those.

Comment: If this was true when posted, it's not anymore. scrapyd runs jobs in parallel. If it seems it's not, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161724/scrapy-s-scrapyd-too-slow-with-scheduling-spiders