# ScrapyDeprecationWaring: Command's default `crawler` is deprecated and will be removed. Use `create_crawler` method to instantiate crawlers

Tags: scrapy

Scrapy version 0.19

I am using the code at this page ( [Run multiple scrapy spiders at once using scrapyd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801093/run-multiple-scrapy-spiders-at-once-using-scrapyd?rq=1) ). When I run `scrapy allcrawl`, I got

```
ScrapyDeprecationWaring: Command's default `crawler` is deprecated and will be removed. Use `create_crawler` method to instantiate crawlers
```

Here is the code:

```
from scrapy.command import ScrapyCommand
import urllib
import urllib2
from scrapy import log

class AllCrawlCommand(ScrapyCommand):

    requires_project = True
    default_settings = {'LOG_ENABLED': False}

    def short_desc(self):
        return "Schedule a run for all available spiders"

    def run(self, args, opts):
        url = 'http://localhost:6800/schedule.json'
        for s in self.crawler.spiders.list(): #this line raise the warning
            values = {'project' : 'YOUR_PROJECT_NAME', 'spider' : s}
            data = urllib.urlencode(values)
            req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
            response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
            log.msg(response)
```

How do I fix the DeprecationWarning ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
crawler = self.crawler_process.create_crawler()
```

Comment: It throws AttributeError: 'CrawlerProcess' object has no attribute 'create_crawler' in scrapy 1.0.3. How to fix this ?

Comment: @Ashish The spider loader it's exposed on `self.crawler_process.spider_loader`, so you can call `.list()` directly on that object.