# Python: Understanding Threading Module

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

While learning Python's *threading* module I've run a simple test. Interesting that the threads are running sequentially and not parallel. Is it possible to modify this test code so a program executes the threads in same fashion as multiprocessing does: in parallel?

```
import threading

def mySlowFunc(arg):
    print "\nStarting...", arg
    m=0
    for i in range(arg):
        m+=i
    print '\n...Finishing', arg

myList =[35000000, 45000000, 55000000]

for each in myList:
    thread = threading.Thread(target=mySlowFunc, args=(each,) )
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()
    thread.join()

print "\n Happy End \n"
```

## REVISED CODE:

This version of the code will initiate 6 'threads' running in 'parallel'. But even while there will be 6 threads only two CPU's threads are actually used (6 other Physical CPU threads will be idling and doing nothing).

```
import threading

def mySlowFunc(arg):
    print "\nStarting " + str(arg) + "..."
    m=0
    for i in range(arg):
        m+=i
    print '\n...Finishing ' + str(arg)

myList =[35000000, 45000000, 55000000, 25000000, 75000000, 65000000]


for each in myList:
    thread = threading.Thread(target=mySlowFunc, args=(each,) )
    thread.daemon = False
    thread.start()

print "\n Bottom of script reached \n"
```

Comment: As mentioned, the gil in Python limits thread performance to one simultaneous thread. If you need true parallelism, you will need multiprocessing, or an alternative implementation like jython.

Comment: If you are using python 2.x, you should use `xrange` instead of `range` for the `mySlowFunc` `for` loop. `range` in python 2.x constructs a list of the specified size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs for the join method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading#threading.Thread.join):

> Wait until the thread terminates. This blocks the calling thread until the thread whose join() method is called terminates – either normally or through an unhandled exception – or until the optional timeout occurs.

Just create a list of threads and join them after launching every single one of them.

Edit:

The threads are executing in parallel, you can think of python's threads like a computer with a single core, the thing is, python's threads are best for IO operations (reading/writing a big file, sending data through a socket, that sort of thing). If you want CPU power you need to use the [multiprocessing module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html)

Comment: Sounds like all we need is to amend thread.join() statement which forces to wait each thread to be completed before starting a new...

Answer (score -1):

If python didn't have the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock), you ought to be able to see true parallelism by changing your code to only join after you have started all threads:

```
threads = []
for each in myList:
  t = threading.Thread(target=mySlowFunc, args=(each,) )
  t.daemon = True
  t.start()
  threads.append(t)
for t in threads:
  t.join()
```

With the above code in python, you should at least be able to see interleaving: thread #2 doing some work before thread #1 has completed. But, you won't see genuine parallelism. See the GIL link for more background.

Comment: Thanks! I actually removed t.join() statement from the code and run it again. Interesting, that I've got 200% CPU utilization with this approach on 800% CPU capable machine. It appears that a single physical CPU is used with both its threads (a reason it shows 200%).

Comment: jrennie, I don't think you achieve anything by appending each thread to a list variable to be used later to run a t.join() method. You could simply put t.join() inside of 'for each in myList:' scope. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Down vote - Bad advice about the GIL, the OP does not understand the basic threading model he should be worried about a implementation detail of CPython

Comment: @hack.augusto I respectfully disagree, but I greatly appreciate that you provided an explanation for the downvote. Thank you!

Comment: @Sputnix, the `join` method blocks until the thread execution ends, if you join the thread before `start`ing a new one you are in fact running sequential code. (I made a typo above, should read "shouldn't" instead of "should", can't edit the comment anymore)

Comment: @jrennie, well, I'm just worried that people new to python get the wrong "python can not do true parallelism" impression, because they do not understand the GIL, but I might be wrong, the OP is wondering why it's code does not use all of its cores. People just don't realise that python's threads *do* work in parallel but with a single thread executing at a time.

Comment: @hack.a: There is a difference in saying: 'they are unaware of GIL' and 'they do not understand the GIL'. I would prefer the first. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @hack.augusto Python's threads *sit* in parallel :) Parallelism refers to parallel processing which is defined as "the ability to carry out multiple operations or tasks simultaneously" which is what native python threads can't do. So, I don't see why you're afraid of people getting the impression that python can't do true parallelism.

Comment: Would you guys please clarify it for me: why do I see only 2 of 8 physically available CPU threads are used on my machine when a code initiates 6 Python threads at the same time? Why doesn't each Python (software) thread take an available physical core(thread)?

Comment: @Sputnix Because of the GIL. David Beazley's presentation is well worth watching/reading IMO http://www.dabeaz.com/python/GIL.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the link. But once again: why do I see only 2 of 8 physically available CPU threads are used on my machine when a code initiates 6 Python threads at the same time? Why doesn't each Python (software) thread take an available physical core(thread)?

Comment: @Sputnix I think I now know the answer to that: the default check interval (see slide 17 of the Beazley talk). The default is 100, which means that every 100 "instructions", the interpreter is retaking control. When I sys.setcheckinterval(10000), I see cpu usage drop dramatically to just over 1 full cpu.