# Easiest way to run scrapy crawler so it doesn't block the script

Tags: python, scrapy

[The official docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-from-script) give many ways for running `scrapy` crawlers from code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    # Your spider definition
    ...

process = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
})

process.crawl(MySpider)
process.start() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
```

But all of them block script until crawling is finished. What's the easiest way in python to run the crawler in a non-blocking, async manner?

Comment: `python yourscript.py &`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried every solution I could find, and the only working for me was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22202877/190148). But in order to make it work with `scrapy 1.1rc1` I had to tweak it a little bit:

```
from scrapy.crawler import Crawler
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from twisted.internet import reactor
from billiard import Process

class CrawlerScript(Process):
    def __init__(self, spider):
        Process.__init__(self)
        settings = get_project_settings()
        self.crawler = Crawler(spider.__class__, settings)
        self.crawler.signals.connect(reactor.stop, signal=signals.spider_closed)
        self.spider = spider

    def run(self):
        self.crawler.crawl(self.spider)
        reactor.run()

def crawl_async():
    spider = MySpider()
    crawler = CrawlerScript(spider)
    crawler.start()
    crawler.join()
```

So now when I call `crawl_async`, it starts crawling and doesn't block my current thread. I'm absolutely new to `scrapy`, so may be this isn't a very good solution but it worked for me.

I used these versions of the libraries:

```
cffi==1.5.0
Scrapy==1.1rc1
Twisted==15.5.0
billiard==3.3.0.22
```

Comment: I tried using your solution, but I got: **AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'Crawler.__init__.<locals>.<lambda>'**. Any idea why?

Comment: The reason is explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25348532/can-python-pickle-lambda-functions

Answer (score 1):

Netimen's answer is correct. `process.start()` calls `reactor.run()`, which blocks the thread. Just that I don't think it is necessary to subclass  `billiard.Process`. Although poorly documented, `billiard.Process` does have a set of APIs to call another function asynchronously without subclassing.

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

from billiard import Process

crawler = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
process = Process(target=crawler.start, stop_after_crawl=False)


def crawl(*args, **kwargs):
    crawler.crawl(*args, **kwargs)
    process.start()
```

Note that if you don't have `stop_after_crawl=False`, you may run into `ReactorNotRestartable` exception when you run the crawler for more than twice.