# CURL couldn't connect to host in scrapy python

Tags: python, curl, scrapy

I am working on scrapy, i am scheduling a spider i had wrote with the following command

```
curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=example -d spider=exampledotcom
```

I am using this by seeing in scrapy tutorial, but when i run above command i used to get the below error

```
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

Why curl is unable to connect to host, is anything wrong in the command ? and also can anyone explain me the concept of why we are using `"http://localhost:6800/schedule.json"`, because finally my intension is to run multiple spiders in a single project.

Comment: And if you type http://localhost:6800/schedule.json in your browser, what do see ?

Comment: @Denis:I am getting this "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost:6800"

Comment: @Dennis:Can u please give an idea of whats happening here so that i can analyze further

Comment: Obviously you try get data from webserver on you local computer, but or you dont have installed webserver on it or its listening another port.

Comment: i had installed web server Apache on my system , i mean when i type localhost or (127.0.0.1) , its working and a page appears for that, any ideas?

Comment: When you type 127.0.0.1 or localhost in your browser its means 127.0.0.1:80 by default, not 6800. Try to read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webserver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scheduling a spider means telling `scrapyd` to run the spider when it can. Thus your have to [run `scrapyd`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/scrapyd.html#starting-scrapyd), before trying to contact it:

```
scrapy server
```

or

```
twistd -ny extras/scrapyd.tac
```

Comment: :Thanks i started scrapyd and deployed a project as in tutorial , actually i am creating multiple spiders in a single project and want all spiders at once, so i had seen this post "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801093/run-multiple-scrapy-spiders-at-once-using-scrapyd", here every thing is working fine and finally in the code i am getting the results of the "response" as "<addinfourl at 58835168 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x37c2bd0>>"

Comment: but nothing happens just giving a response

Comment: but the intension of the above code in the post is to run multiple spider and execute spider, in my case spider should write all the data to json file.My spider is working fine and when i used individually its storing to json files, i am trying what if more spider files are there so i had created a custom command for running multiple spiders

Comment: here i am only getting response but it seems the spider in allcrawl.py(custom command) i had written is not workong

Comment: When you schedule a spider you send a request to scrapyd, and it just returns the result of scheduling - a json answer with job_id and similar. scrapyd starts your spider either immediately or when it finds it appropriate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161724/scrapy-s-scrapyd-too-slow-with-scheduling-spiders