# Running multiple spiders using scrapyd

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, scrapyd

I had multiple spiders in my project so decided to run them by uploading to scrapyd server.
I had uploaded my project succesfully and i can see all the spiders when i run the command

```
curl http://localhost:6800/listspiders.json?project=myproject
```

when i run the following command

```
curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=myproject -d spider=spider2
```

Only one spider runs because of only one spider given, but i want to run run multiple spiders here so the following command is right  for running multiple spiders in scrapyd ?

```
curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=myproject -d spider=spider1,spider2,spider3........
```

And later i will run this command using cron job i mean i will schedule this to run frequently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run multiple spiders using scrapyd, schedule them one by one. scrapyd will run them in the same order but not at the same time.

See also: [Scrapy 's Scrapyd too slow with scheduling spiders](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9161724/248296)

Comment: Yes i mean to run all the spiders with one command, not all concurrently. After deploying a project with multiple spiders how can i schedule them with using scrapyd, whether above command is useful ?

Comment: Your command is invalid. http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/scrapyd.html#schedule-json says that `spider` argument should contain spider name, but you provided a list of spider names delimited by commas. Instead of doing `http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=myproject -d spider=spider1,spider2` do `http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=myproject -d spider=spider1` then `http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=myproject -d spider=spider2`, and so on

Comment: if we do so i expect this will be same as "scrapy crawl spider_name" command, then why we uploaded this to scrapyd server, suppose if want to run all these through cron jobs i need to write all the commands in more than one lines right?

Comment: Actually, when scrapyd runs a spider it uses almost the [same command](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/scrapyd.html#how-scrapyd-works) as "scrapy crawl spider_name"

Comment: oh thanks warwaruk, but how can we run the spiders one by one then, because now i am trying to run all the spiders(for example 4 spiders) through cron jobs, isthere any way to run all the spiders one by one and schedule them to run for every 2 or more hours

Comment: make a bash script which issues commands for scheduling all your spiders, and put that push script to cron. Alternatively, it can be a python script which does the same, without calling curl. An example is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801093/run-multiple-scrapy-spiders-at-once-using-scrapyd)